# Haproxy errorfile cannot be read

Tags: haproxy

I have the following Haproxy config:

```
frontend http-in
    mode http
    bind :80

    option forwardfor
    option httplog
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    default_backend http-routers

    errorfile 502 /var/haproxy/404.http
    acl is_internal_error status eq 404
    rspdeny . if is_internal_error
```

When I hit the url for non existing domain, ex: http://test.example.com
I receive a timeout error (408).

However, when I retrieve the line `errorfile 502 /var/haproxy/404.http`, I can see the default error msg of 502 error code.

Can anyone tell why Haproxy cannot read my file  `/var/haproxy/404.http`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of [Haproxy behind ELB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376997/haproxy-behind-elb/43531146#43531146).

TL;DR;
Problems with erro_file newline format. 
You need a ^M on HTTP INFO lines, not needed on the response body. 
Dont know why, but it behaves that way. hope it helps. 
[Example file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/haproxy/haproxy/60220bbc4b6b3c4279d3c96232cf2c2461ecc55e/examples/errorfiles/503.http) has those when open in vi(m). Don't copy the contents, it looks the same but isn't.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like permissions problem right off the bat. What user is haproxy running as? Can you post the permissions of /var/haproxy/404.http?

Comment: haproxy runs as a root.  and i changed the permission of /var/haproxy/404.http to 777 (chmod 777 ). but it s still the same problem

Comment: It seems that the root cause is AWS ELB. Actually, i have HAproxy is behind an AWS ELB. As soon as i remove the ELB, i can get the custom error page. but, with ELB in the front of Haproxy,  i get   `HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive`. Can anyone tell me what is going on please.  Thanks.

Comment: It s solved in this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376997/haproxy-behind-elb