# Haproxy behind ELB

Tags: haproxy, amazon-elb

I have HAproxy is behind an AWS ELB. As soon as i remove the ELB, i can get the custom error page. but, with ELB in the front of Haproxy, i get HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive.

Can anyone tell me what is going on please? Thanks

errorfile:

```
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>
```

Comment: Does the ELB show the instance as healthy?  Does HAProxy log anything for the failed request?

Comment: Yes, the ELB show the instance as healthy.
Does HAProxy log anything for the failed request? No

Answer (score 2):

Me and a coworker just had the same problem. After receiving the timeouts, and reading amazon definition for this type of http code, i got in my head my error file was "malformed". After a lot of trys, we managed to discover that there is something funny with the CL-RF (new lines) on the error file "header".

I downloaded HaProxy default file from their git (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/haproxy/haproxy/60220bbc4b6b3c4279d3c96232cf2c2461ecc55e/examples/errorfiles/503.http) and when you open it on vi(m) it has a ^M (CR) sign on the headers(everything before the body, including the empty line separating them). If you cant download it, you could just write it (just the top part) on wordpad or something like it (dos) and then send it to you unix machine.

So i wrote my on file using their header and now everything works fine. 
Cheers.

Comment: @FadhelGhorbel then please accept the answer by clicking the tick